# Duplicate particle emitter

Tags: particles, system

How to duplicate particle system, please clearly explain how to do. And I will show a pic of the particle emitter to change the name of the 1st step so [image]I want to duplicate the 1st step so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Next time provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

**To duplicate** the settings just add another particle system with the <kbd>+</kbd>, and choose the same value from the *Settings* combobox (*ParticleSettings* in your case). Note: the *Seed* value is not copied and will reset to 0 for some reason.

**To change the name** of the particle system or the settings just **double-click** the name and you can edit it. Note: Once you have edited the hair (*Comb mode*), all values become read-only, including the name of the settings.

[image: demo gif]
<sup>Hair particle settngs, Blender 2.9x</sup>